# Gif over an html link image

Tags: html, css

I am creating a profile, and want to add a gif over the html link image and place it where i want. When i do it just goes on top of the image?

```html
<img src="https://i.ibb.co/s1zKHdw/c.gif" alt="Smiley face" width="159" height="93";IMG STYLE="position:absolute; BOTTOM:365px; LEFT:418px; SRC="circle.gif">

<a href="https://ibb.co/g9W5230"><img src="<a href="https://ibb.co/NZRmgxy"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/Fgp0k6D/Copy-of-Profile-Finish.png"; alt="Copy-of-Profile-Finish" border="0"></a>;><
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ Unfortunately no-one will be able to help you unless you can add your code to the question _ Please take a moment to visit SO Help Center and specifically the question on which parts of the code you should be adding >>> https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: if it just goes ontop of the image, this means you probably don't have css code to change the `width`,`height`,`position`,`float` etc.